# Objective C + Reskit - How do I wrap my dictionary with a key to avoid formatting problems?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, dictionary, restkit

I'm trying to wrap my HTTP POST request with a key. In other words, I want to turn this:

```
{
"category_id"=>"1", 
"food_name_token"=>"Pizza", 
 "id"=>"1"
}
```

into this:

```
{
"dish" => 
    {
    "category_id"=>"1", 
    "food_name_token"=>"Pizza", 
    "id"=>"1"
    }
}
```

I tried using the 'rootKeyPath' method in RestKit:

```
serializationMapping.rootKeyPath = @"dish";
```

But that gave me this weirdly formatted string :

```
{
"dish"=>
    "{
    \n \"category_id\" = 1; 
    \n \"food_name_token\" = Pizza;
    \n id = 1;
    \n}
"}
```

It uses equal signs and semicolons instead of arrows and commas, and adds in all these linebreaks and escape backslashes.

Any idea why? And any suggestions on what I can do instead?

P.S. I'm using a Rails backend

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521683/nsdictionary-description-formatting-problem-treats-structure-like-char-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out with Restkit I can wrap attributes using brackets:

```
    [dishMapping mayKeyPath:@"dish[food_name_token]" toAttribute:@"placeToken"];
```

And this gives me a normal output without the weird formatting.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDictionary *rootDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:childDict forKey:@"dish"];
```

This should solve it.

Comment: and how does Jonathan get childDict?

Comment: Your answer made me realize that the problem doesn't lie in RestKit's 'rootKeyPath' method, because I tried your solution and it produces the same result.  Instead the problem lies in the way Objective C serializes my Dictionary object.  Even if it's wrapped the proper way, it still gives me these extra escaped strings that make it hard for the server to parse. It doesn't answer my question fully, but it does answer the question I put out as my title (although I realized it's the wrong question to ask, so I probably should change it). So I'll just give you a vote up.

Answer (score 0):

Add the items into an NSArray, and then add the array into the NSDictionary, like this:

```
NSDictionary *item = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:results], @"Parent",nil];
NSLog(@"NSDicitonary %@",item);
NSLog(@"Child values %@",[item valueForKey:@"Parent"]);
```

Comment: I read about using arrays as well from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521683/nsdictionary-description-formatting-problem-treats-structure-like-char-data  But I don't understand how to implement it his way.