# NSDictionary-like pretty-print in the debugger (or log)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, lldb

This has been bugging me for a while. How do I counteract the ugly escaping that happens when dumping objects in the debugger with `po foo` (or via `NSLog`). I've tried numerous approaches to implementing `-description` or `-debugDescription` to no avail.

Given this simple class

```m
@interface Foo : NSObject
@property NSDictionary* dict;
@end

@implementation Foo
- (NSString *)description {
    // super.description for the <{classname} pointer> output
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", super.description, self.dict];
}
@end
```

And contrived usage

```m
Foo* f0 = [[Foo alloc] init];
f0.dict = @{ @"value": @0, @"next": NSNull.null };
Foo* f1 = [[Foo alloc] init];
f1.dict = @{ @"value": @1, @"next": f0 };
Foo* f2 = [[Foo alloc] init];
f2.dict = @{ @"value": @2, @"next": f1 };
```

We get nice output for `f0`

```
(lldb) po f0
<Foo: 0x8cbc410> {
    next = "<null>";
    value = 0;
}
```

Tolerable output for `f1`

```
(lldb) po f1
<Foo: 0x8cbc480> {
    next = "<Foo: 0x8cbc410> {\n    next = \"<null>\";\n    value = 0;\n}";
    value = 1;
}
```

And horrendous output for `f2`

```
(lldb) po f2
<Foo: 0x8cbc4b0> {
    next = "<Foo: 0x8cbc480> {\n    next = \"<Foo: 0x8cbc410> {\\n    next = \\\"<null>\\\";\\n    value = 0;\\n}\";\n    value = 1;\n}";
    value = 2;
}
```

This gets hard to parse fast when debugging real world object hierarchies. I'm assuming there's some other trick I'm missing since dumping a similarly nested NSDictionary

```m
NSDictionary* d0 = @{ @"value": @0, @"next": NSNull.null };
NSDictionary* d1 = @{ @"value": @1, @"next": d0 };
NSDictionary* d2 = @{ @"value": @2, @"next": d1 };
```

Maintains the indenting and avoids the escaping hell

```
(lldb) po d2
{
    next =     {
        next =         {
            next = "<null>";
            value = 0;
        };
        value = 1;
    };
    value = 2;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Switching to `-debugDescription` and simply forwarding to the dictionary

```
@implementation Foo
- (NSString *)debugDescription {
    return self.dict.debugDescription;
}
@end
```

loses the recursive output

```
(lldb) po f2
{
    next = "<Foo: 0x8b70e20>";
    value = 2;
}
```

Internally `NSDictionary` must be relying on `-description` which I'm not implementing in this example, only `-debugDescription`. Switching to something like the following

```
@implementation Foo
- (NSString *)description {
    return self.dict.description;
}
- (NSString *)debugDescription {
    return self.dict.debugDescription;
}
@end
```

produces similarly bad output as well

```
(lldb) po f2
{
    next = "{\n    next = \"{\\n    next = \\\"<null>\\\";\\n    value = 0;\\n}\";\n    value = 1;\n}";
    value = 2;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `self.dict` with `[self.dict debugDescription]` in your `Foo description` method?

Comment: @rmaddy Sadly it produces the same output. Not surprising since both `-[NSDictionary description]` and `-[NSDictionary debugDescription]` produce the same output. This isn't the case for `NSArray` which produces IMO worse output for `-debugDescription`. However, `NSArray` still suffers from similar escaping problems in both cases.

Comment: When you do `po d2` in the debugger it should call `debugDescription`. Since that seems to give good output, I hoped calling that explicitly would help. What if you implement `Foo debugDescription` and call `debugDescription` on your objects?

Comment: @rmaddy Yea, but by default `-debugDescription` simply delegates to `-description` unless explicitly overridden. `NSArray` is one such place I'm aware of that does this but `NSDictionary` doesn't. I'll edit my question to expand on this some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR;

Use [NSContainers-PrettyPrint](http://openradar.appspot.com/10765424) and carefully [read](https://github.com/NSError/NSContainers-PrettyPrint/blob/master/String-Tools.md) the [docs](https://github.com/NSError/NSContainers-PrettyPrint/blob/master/Best-Practices.md).

#### Long Answer

After much more searching I discovered the [`descriptionWithLocale:indent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/descriptionWithLocale:indent:) method. As documented, I should've been able to implement this in my own classes to achieve the desired pretty-print formatting. However, after some failed attempts I found a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521683/nsdictionary-description-formatting-problem-treats-structure-like-char-data). Turns out `descriptionWithLocale:indent:` only works if you subclass a Foundation container class because of "security concerns".

Unsatisfied with that approach I continued digging and found this [radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/10765424) but also a solution in [NSContainers-PrettyPrint](https://github.com/NSError/NSContainers-PrettyPrint). After some trial and error I got things working decently well. (It's not on CocoaPods so you have to add it manually).

Once NSContainers-PrettyPrint is added you'll probably want [JRSwizzle](https://github.com/rentzsch/jrswizzle) too. Then define `DEBUGPRINT_ALL` and `DEBUGPRINT_SWIZZLE` in your DEBUG targets preprocessor macros. Finally, you can implement your `descriptionWithLocale:indent:` methods in terms of the [fs_* helpers](https://github.com/NSError/NSContainers-PrettyPrint/blob/master/String-Tools.md) and [best practices](https://github.com/NSError/NSContainers-PrettyPrint/blob/master/Best-Practices.md).

Using the same `Foo` from my question as an example

```
@implementation Foo
- (NSString*)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", super.description, self.dict.description];
}

- (NSString *)descriptionWithLocale:(id)locale indent:(NSUInteger)level
{
    NSString * indent = [NSString fs_stringByFillingWithCharacter:' ' repeated:fspp_spacesPerIndent*level];
    NSMutableString * str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [str fs_appendObjectStartWithIndentString:indent caller:self];
    [str appendString:[self.dict descriptionWithLocale:locale indent:level+1]];
    [str fs_appendObjectEnd];
    return str;
}
@end
```

Would produce the following output given the same `f0`, `f1` and `f2` instances

```
(lldb) po f0
<Foo: 0x8a385c0> {
    value = 0;
    next = <null>;
}
(lldb) po f1
<Foo: 0x8a38630> {
    value = 1;
    next = <Foo:0x8a385c0        {
            value = 0;
            next = <null>;
        }>;
}
(lldb) po f2
<Foo: 0x8a38660> {
    value = 2;
    next = <Foo:0x8a38630        {
            value = 1;
            next = <Foo:0x8a385c0                {
                    value = 0;
                    next = <null>;
                }>;
        }>;
}
```

The above `descriptionWithLocale:indent:` could use some tweaking to reduce the excessive whitespace but it still beats the alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

A similar question ([NSDictionary `description` formatting problem — treats structure like char data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521683/nsdictionary-description-formatting-problem-treats-structure-like-char-data)) suggested that `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` are in some way cheating and not calling `-[NSObject respondsToSelector:@selector(descriptionWithLocale:indent:)`. This appears to be true.

To test this I created an `NSProxy` which log all calls. The test was:

```
NSObject *proxy = [LoggingProxy proxyWithTarget:[[NSObject alloc] init]];
NSLog(@"%@", @[proxy]);
```

The results were:

```
message: isNSString__
message: isNSDictionary__
message: isNSArray__
message: isNSData__

2014-05-29 15:29:22.728 Proxy[36219:303] (
    "<LoggingProxy: 0x100103510>"
)
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

In my real objects I added the method:

```
#if DEBUG
- (BOOL) isNSDictionary__
{
    return YES;
}
#endif
```

`NSArray` and `NSDictionary` then behaved as you'd hope by calling `-[NSObject respondsToSelector:@selector(descriptionWithLocale:indent:)`. Make sure that if you return `YES` you really have implemented `descriptionWithLocale:indent:` as it will be called with out checking it's really there.

**Please remember to wrap this method in** `#if DEBUG`. You really don't want to be shipping this, but it seems fine for use in Xcode.