# What method to implement on a subclass of NSObject to allow pretty-printing in swift playground?

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift-playground

Is there a way to pretty-print custom objective-c objects in a Xcode 7.2 swift playground?  As in, I have some objective-c classes and would like to implement the protocol(s) needed for pretty print support ...

Any pointers would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but I think it would be similar to this question regarding overriding the `description` and/or `descriptionWithLocale:indent:` methods of NSObject.

[NSDictionary-like pretty-print in the debugger (or log)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346738/nsdictionary-like-pretty-print-in-the-debugger-or-log)