# Sending JSONArray via NSDictionary in AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary, afnetworking

normally I will put those param into an nsdictionary and send it out like this:

```
params:{
    deviceType = ios;
    a = "rgergregeververververver";
    b = "123123";
}
```

and now one of the param is a json string of an array of object.
so I convert my array of object in to json string.
the output json string is expected as follow:

```
[
  {
    "a" : "aaaa",
    "b" : "bbbb",
    "c" : "cccc"
  },
  {
    "a" : "eeee",
    "b" : "ffff",
    "c" : "gggg",
  }
]
```

and put this as "data" in my params
and I print the nsdiction it shows the following:

```
params:{
    data = "[\n  {\n    \"a\" : \"aaaa\",\n    \"b\" : \"bbbb\",\n    \"c\" : \"cccc\"},\n  {\n    \"a\" : \"aaaa\",\n    \"b\" : \"bbbb\",\n    \"c\" : \"cccc\"}\n]";
    deviceType = ios;
    a = "12312312312312";
    b = "4355242341421582946";
}
```

there are some \n and back slash before double quote. If it is a problem? or it is just the display from [dict description]?

Comment: It's fine.  [See this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521683/nsdictionary-description-formatting-problem-treats-structure-like-char-data)

Comment: Whatever was used to serialize the JSON produced a "formatted" version, which is a bit strange but not harmful.  If you did the serialization with NSJSONSerialization you have an unnecessary `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted` option specified.